# Stein-Shakarchi Complex Analysis Fourier Inversion Theorem Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Providing background from the previous parts of the question, we are asked:

> Define:
>   $$\hat f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi izt}dt$$
>   where $f$ is entire and is smooth ($\mathbf{C^2}$). Let:
>   $$P(z)=a_n(2\pi iz)^n+...+a_0$$ where $a_j$ is a complex constant.
>   Set $u(t)=\int_L\frac{e^{2\pi izt}}{P(z)}\hat f(z)dz$, where $L$ is the line along which $P(z)$ does not vanish. Check that:
>   $$\sum_{j=0}^na_j\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\Big)^ju(t)=\int_Le^{2\pi izt}\hat f(z)dz$$
>   and:
>   $$\int_Le^{2\pi izt}\hat f(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\pi ixt}\hat f(x)dx$$
>   Conclude by Fourier Inversion Theorem that:
>   $$\sum_{j=0}^na_j\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\Big)^ju(t)=f(t)$$

While I understand the intuition behind the problem, I'm slightly confused as to how to proceed. I understand that it's a fairly straightforward calculation, but for one reason or another I'm not getting the desired result. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no question in your post, you wrote all the proof. Together with the Fourier inversion theorem, the point you need to investigate is the precise definition of $L$ and when is it true that $\hat{f}(z)$ is well-defined and analytic for $\Im(z) \in (-a,a)$ and when can we say that $\int_Le^{2\pi izt}\hat f(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\pi ixt}\hat f(x)dx$ (Cauchy integral theorem + decay of $\hat{f}$) as well as the differentiability of $u(t)$.